# crear reloj e insertarlo en una tabla

Tags: javascript, html5, while, html-tabla

Hola estoy buscando hacer un reloj que imprima la hora, minutos y segundos con un bucle `while` e insertarlo en una tabla. Estoy recién en esto, y no me doy mucha idea de como hacerlo. agradecería mucho si que me prestaran una ayuda.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

<body>

  <table width="200" border="1">

  <tbody>

  <tr>
    <th>Horas</th>
    <th>Minutos</th>
    <th>Segundos</th>
  </tr>

  </thead>

  <tbody id="resultado">
  </tbody>

  </table>


<script type="text/javascript">

var a = "";
var h = 0;
var m = 0;
var s = 0;

a += "<tr>"
+ "<td>" + h + "</td>"
+ "<td>" + m + "</td>"
+ "<td>" + s + "</td>"
+ "</tr>";


while(h < 24){ 
    h++; 

while(m < 60){ 
    m++;

while(s < 60){ 
    s++;
document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = a;
}

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tienes un par de errores en tu codigo, como llaves para cerrar los `while`, tambien etiquetas sin etiquetas de cierre, de igual forma, echale un ojo a este ejemplo seguro te sirve, [ejemplo](http://www.forosdelweb.com/f13/mostrar-hora-minutos-segundos-dinamicamente-869034/)

Answer (score 2):

Creo que esto te puede servir:

```js
var h = 0;
var m = 0;
var s = 0;
const hora = document.getElementById("hora");
const minutos = document.getElementById("minutos");
const segundos = document.getElementById("segundos");
minutos.textContent = m;
hora.textContent = h;
segundos.textContent = s;

setInterval(function(){
  if (s === 59){
    s = -1; // Para que al final del bloque termine siendo 0
    m++;
    minutos.textContent = m;
  }
  if (m === 60){
    m = 0;
    h++;
    hora.textContent = h;
    minutos.textContent = m;
  }
  if(h === 24){
    h = 0;
    hora.textContent = h;
  }
  s++;
  segundos.textContent = s;
}, 1000);
```

```html
  <table width="200" border="1">

  <tbody>

  <tr>
    <th>Horas</th>
    <th>Minutos</th>
    <th>Segundos</th>
  </tr>

  </thead>

  <tbody id="resultado">
    <tr>
      <td id="hora"></td>
      <td id="minutos"></td>
      <td id="segundos"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  </table>
```

En este caso tener en la variable `a` la fila y las celdas es poco conveniente pues cada vez se "crea" la tabla, mejor es crearla desde HTML y reescribirla en JS, para eso ocupas el `textContent`.

Luego con `setInterval` creas un intervalo que ejecuta la **función** cada **x** tiempo en milisegundos, así:

`setInterval(función, x);`

Si quieres hacerlo con la fecha actual podrías *instanciar* un objeto de la clase `Date()` y obtener las horas, minutos y segundos. Justo como a continuación:

```js
  //Obtener variables
var fecha = new Date();
var h = fecha.getHours();
var m = fecha.getMinutes();
var s = fecha.getSeconds();
  //Obtener los elementos a sobreescribir
const hora = document.getElementById("hora");
const minutos = document.getElementById("minutos");
const segundos = document.getElementById("segundos");
  //Imprimir lo primero
minutos.textContent = m;
hora.textContent = h;
segundos.textContent = s;

setInterval(function(){
  if (s === 59){
    s = -1; // Para que al final del código termine siendo 0
    m++;
    minutos.textContent = m;
  }
  if (m === 60){
    m = 0;
    h++;
    hora.textContent = h;
    minutos.textContent = m;
  }
  if(h === 24){
    h = 0;
    hora.textContent = h;
  }
  s++;
  segundos.textContent = s;
}, 1000);
```

```html
  <table width="200" border="1">

  <tbody>

  <tr>
    <th>Horas</th>
    <th>Minutos</th>
    <th>Segundos</th>
  </tr>

  </thead>

  <tbody id="resultado">
    <tr>
      <td id="hora"></td>
      <td id="minutos"></td>
      <td id="segundos"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  </table>
```

Comment: setInterval no asegura que se ejecute exactamente cada 1000 ms (cómo es en tu caso), lo mejor sería consultar el tiempo con new Date() en milisegundos y esto consultarlo cada un milisegundo que es el mínimo que soporta setInterval, o mejor aún crear un evento que este atento cada vez que aumenta en un segundo la hora.

Comment: Exacto, puse ese ejemplo porque era el que más se parecía a lo que _mati_ puso en la pregunta, pues va empezando y siento que no va tanto enfocado a mostrar exacta la hora ni a intervalos o así, sino más bien va enfocado a la resolución del problema con contadores y condicionales, por ello no quise extenderme a soluciones como las que planteas @Javi, que de hecho son mejores.

Answer (score 0):

Como en la otra respuesta una solución sin `while`, pero rápida y mínima, con layout de tabla y un poco de CSS ([**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/z4b35ypw/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>Reloj</title>
<style>
table,td{border:1px solid #000}
td{padding:15px;width:45px;text-align:right}
</style>
<script>
<!--
function miReloj() {//
  let data=new Date(),
    hh=data.getHours(),
    mi=data.getMinutes(),
    ss=data.getSeconds();
  document.getElementById("relojh").innerText=hh;
  document.getElementById("relojm").innerText=mi;
  document.getElementById("relojs").innerText=ss;
  window.setTimeout("miReloj()", 1000);
}
//-->
</script>
</head>

<body onload="miReloj()">
<table>
<tr>
  <td><span id="relojh"></span></td>
  <td><span id="relojm"></span></td>
  <td><span id="relojs"></span></td>
</td>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo siento pero solo hablo italiano y utilicé el traductor de Google :)